# Pass array (or TList) from C# code behind to external javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, tlist

I need to pass a list (or array) of IP addresses and other information from C# code behind to the javascript function, which is in the external .js..

Also, this list may be long (1000+ items) .. What is the most efficient way to do this? can you provide a small example? should I use json serialization?

Comment: Isn't TList Delphi? Do you mean List<T>?

Answer (score 0):

`var myObject = <%= JustSerializeAsJson(...) %>;` ... or pass it to a function to whatever. Point is JSON is a valid JavaScript literal so you can drop it in a number of places. Don't worry about "efficiency" here unless there is a *profiled* problem. Both the generation and JavaScript parsing should be *really fast*. (Bing maps loads like 1MB file in JS!)

[MSDN JSON Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx)