# How can I cycle an array on javascript made on C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

I have this JS function :

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    alert(myArray[i]);
}
```

but `myArray[]` is create on server side with c# :

```
ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (MyObject myobject in MyObjects)
    {
        myArray.Add(myobject.Description);
    }
}
```

so, how can I "pass" the C# array to Javascript? Or I need to print the whole javascript code on server side and send it to the server?

Comment: Possible duplicates: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331146/how-to-pass-array-from-asp-net-server-side-to-javascript-function-on-client-side
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464498/pass-c-asp-net-array-to-javascript-array
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799551/pass-array-or-tlist-from-c-code-behind-to-external-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at before...

1)I will put a hidden in the page...

2) general a string like

```
"['a','b','c']"
```

into the hidden at .cs

3) cast to the array from the string at javascript

```
var arr = eval(hiddenvalue);
```

4)  use it as a array...

Answer (score 5):

You can populate javascript array from serverside by using `RegisterArrayDeclaration(arrayName, arrayValue)` method.

In Cs file

```
RegisterArrayDeclaration("FavoriteNumbers", "1")
RegisterArrayDeclaration("FavoriteNumbers", "2")
RegisterArrayDeclaration("FavoriteNumbers", "3")
```

In javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
   var FavoriteNumbers =  new Array(1, 2, 3);
      // -->
</script>
```

Comment: Y?? What ? don't know what you mean :)

Answer (score 4):

You could create json object(array) that would be serialized and sent to client where you can work with it as with Javascript array.

You can use

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var output = serializer.Serialize(your_anon_object);
```

from

```
System.Web.Extensions.dll
```

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize your C# array as JSON. [You can read in detail about it here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)
Also I would suggest using List<> instead of ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PageMethods to access functions in your code behind. Simply create a function to access your property.

Example here, http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/21456-Page-Method.aspx